# Как достать объект из JSON файла?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы переменная была равна объекту который находится в JSON
console.log(data) возврщает то что мне нужно, но как мне записать это значение

```
const obj = fetch("obj.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
console.log(obj)
```

Содержимое JSON просто объект

```
{
  "distance": { "unit": "in", "value": 10 },
  "convert_to": "m"
}
```

Comment: Объявить переменную до использования `fetch` (также можно объявить глобальную переменную), и сохранить при в эту переменную `data`. (Пример: `window.result = null; /* Ваш код с fetch... */ (data) => window.result = data}); console.log(window.result)`

Comment: @ΝNL993, это ведь не сработает, `console.log(window.result)` выведется раньше, чем обработается `fetch`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Да, вы правы

Comment: @OliverPatterson предполагается что console.log будет в методе `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете получить данные в переменную, если будете использовать синтаксис `async/await`, но для этого вам нужно это все выполнять в `async` функции.

```js
async function test()
{
    const obj = await fetch("obj.json").then((response) => response.json());

    console.log(obj);
}

test();
```

Comment: Не особо понимаю решение, так как по итогу объект все еще доступен только внутри функции и по сути можно просто использовать еще 1 `.then` и в него уже засунуть всю свою функцию и там использовать объект

Comment: Если вы хотите получить значение так в "глобальное" выполнение, то этого не получится.

Comment: Печально( Использую среду Noda не задумываешься о таких вещах(

Comment: Кхм.. Тогда попробуйте код из функции достать. В NodeJS если не ошибаюсь можно использовать await.

Comment: Та вот суть в том что в ноде вообще проблем нет( Просто именным экспортом и все, а тут целый геморой